# Gmail (API) - weird empty messages appeared from year 1970

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am working on Gmail API and I am fetching emails. My first step is to list all threads and then call `get` method for each. However some listed threads can't be reached via `get` method.

Sample error #1:

```
{ Error: Not Found
    at Request._callback (/home/kuno/code/an_api/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/kuno/code/an_api/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/kuno/code/an_api/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1057:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/kuno/code/an_api/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1003:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
  code: 404,
  errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ] }
```

Sample error #2:

```
{ Error: Requested entity was not found.
    at Request._callback (/home/kuno/code/an_api/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/kuno/code/an_api/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/kuno/code/an_api/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1057:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/kuno/code/an_api/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1003:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
  code: 404,
  errors: 
   [ { message: 'Requested entity was not found.',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'notFound' } ] }
```

When I try to reach these messages directly from Gmail (browser app) this is how they look like:

[image]

Attachment is an empty `.txt` file. Note it is sent from (void) and sent to (void) on year 1970.

What are those messages? Why do they appear? How to filter/ignore/delete them?

Comment: Intreresting. Could you click the top-most arrow `More`, `Show Original` and include the original message text in the question?

Comment: @Tholle It would return blank page. Also I want to mention that I didn't use filter by label in request so right now I am fetching everything (including hangouts chat)  rather than just messages labeled as INBOX. Other than that, this appears for both old accounts and new ones (created this month)